# Regex validate string if it does not contain list of special character and allowed special character followed by alphanumeric

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate string that

1. don’t allow these characters at all:  ! @ # $ % ^ & * | \ [ ] { } ? > < ” ’ ; :
2. allow the following only if regular characters are also present:  . , + = _ -

This is what I tried so far but it is not validating the second condition that validate allowed character if alphanumeric characters are also exists in the string

```
([^\!\@\#\$%\^&\*\|\\[\]\{\}\?\>\<”\’\;\:]|([\.\,\+\=\_\-A-Za-z0-9]))
```

Test - https://regex101.com/r/u6osVm/2

Comment: I suspect you just need `^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9.,+=_-]+$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6osVm/3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9.,+=_-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6osVm/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])` - there must be an ASCII alphanumeric char after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `[A-Za-z0-9.,+=_-]+` - 1+ ASCII letters, digits, `.`, `,`, `+`, `=`, `_`, `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.